GitLab & Docker-in-Docker: Unable to bind volume when confirmed it exists (with absolute path)
Disclaimer
There's a lot of this information I can't readily share, because it is a private GitLab instance, and my company has strict rules about access and code sharing. I will provide what I can to illustrate my problems
Problem
I am trying to write an automated test pipeline stage that will use Docker Compose to pull in a Selenium Grid configuration, while running a Node.js container that controls the tests using Cucumber. When I run docker compose up I am getting the following error: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /tmp/artifactorytoken.env. However, at the start of the stage, I print out the contents of the /tmp directory (that I compose at runtime) and here was the result:
$ ls -l /tmp
total 24
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2376 Aug 29 19:46 artifactorytoken.env
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           105 Aug 29 19:46 artifactoryuser.env
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug 29 19:46 docker-compose-out
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5982 Aug 29 19:46 pipeline.env

Code
So, I can't provide the config.toml for the runner (because I don't have access to it), but I can provide a snippet of my GitLab pipeline code, as well as my Dockerfile and the relevant contents (some script files)
Dockerfile
FROM docker:dind as base

ENV DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE="./infra/local/docker-compose.yml" \
  DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROFILE="ci" \
  ENV="/etc/profile"

ADD --chmod=755 . /
RUN initialize-container

FROM base as docker-image
WORKDIR /opt/app-root
ENTRYPOINT [ "custom-dockerd-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD []

GitLab pipeline code
.cucumberjs:base:
  variables:
    DIND_IMAGE: $IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image
    ENV: /etc/profile
  before_script:
    - source "$ENV"

.cucumberjs:docker:
  extends:
    - .cucumberjs:base
  image: $DIND_IMAGE
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: "true"
  services:
    - name: $DIND_IMAGE
      alias: docker
  script:
    - integration-test

.cucumberjs:unit-test:
  needs: []
  before_script:
    - cd "$APX_UNIT_PATH"
    - source "$ENV"

.cucumberjs:docker:unit-test:
  extends:
    - .cucumberjs:docker
    - .cucumberjs:unit-test
  variables:
    APX_UNIT_PATH: tests/docker

cucumberjs:docker:integration:
  stage: integration
  extends:
    - .cucumberjs:docker

cucumberjs:docker:integration:unit-test:
  extends:
    - cucumberjs:docker:integration
    - .cucumberjs:docker:unit-test

Shell scripts

/usr/local/bin/initialize-container

#!/bin/sh

apk update
apk upgrade
apk add curl jq util-linux yq
mkdir -p /opt/app-root /tmp/docker-compose-out


/usr/local/bin/custom-dockerd-entrypoint.sh

#!/bin/sh

echo Custom Docker Daemon entrypoint script
source "$ENV"
dockerInitEnv

echo Listing files that should have been created by dockerInitEnv
ls -l /tmp
echo Begin standard Docker Daemon entrypoint

/usr/local/bin/dockerd-entrypoint.sh "$@"


/usr/local/bin/integration-test

#!/bin/sh
source /etc/profile

if ! docker system info; then
  echo Unable to gather information about the Docker Engine. Exiting
  exit 1
fi

_exit_code=0
if validateVars DOCKER_URL DOCKER_USER DOCKER_TOKEN; then
  if testSetup; then
    if dockerIntegrationTest; then
      echo Successfully ran Docker Integration tests
    else
      _exit_code="$_exit_code $?"
      echo Docker Integration tests failed with exit code $_exit_code
    fi

    if testTeardown; then
      echo Successful teardown of Docker Integration tests
    else
      _exit_code="$_exit_code $?"
      echo Unable to perform teardown procedures. Exit code $_exit_code
    fi
  else
    _exit_code="$_exit_code $?"
    echo Test Setup procedures failed with exit code "$_exit_code"
  fi
else
  _exit_code="$_exit_code $?"
  echo One or more required variables were undefined. Exiting with code $_exit_code
fi

exit "$(echo $_exit_code | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | tail -n1)"


/etc/profile.d/test-setup.sh

testSetup() {
  if dockerLogin; then
    if dockerInitEnv; then
      dockerCompose up --wait
    fi
  fi
  
  return $?
}


/etc/profile.d/docker/init-environment.sh

dockerInitEnv() {
  rm -rf /tmp/docker-compose-out
  mkdir /tmp/docker-compose-out

  enumerateVars ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN /tmp/artifactorytoken.env
  enumerateVars ARTIFACTORY_USER /tmp/artifactoryuser.env
  for _varName in APX_CUCUMBERJS_ENV APX_CUCUMBERJS_PATH APX_CUCUMBERJS_STAGE; do
    enumerateVars "$_varName" /tmp/pipeline.env
  done
  
  if test -f "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE"; then
    echo "Compose file indicated was found at '$(realpath "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE")'"
    return 0
  elif test -d "$APX_DOCKER_COMPOSE_DIRECTORY"; then
    echo "Searching for a Docker Compose file in the directory '$(realpath "$APX_DOCKER_COMPOSE_DIRECTORY")'"
    export DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE="$(find "$APX_DOCKER_COMPOSE_DIRECTORY" -type f -name docker-compose*.y*l -print -quit)"
  fi
  
  if test -f "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE"; then
    echo "Compose file was discovered at '$(realpath "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE")'"
    return 0
  else
    echo "Searching for any Docker Compose file in the current working directory '$PWD'"
    export DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE="$(find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 4 -type f -name docker-compose*.y*l -print -quit)"
  fi
  
  if test -f "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE"; then
    echo "Compose file was discovered at '$(realpath "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE")'"
    return 0
  else
    echo Unable to determine Docker Compose file to run.
    return 1
  fi
}


/etc/profile.d/docker/compose.sh

dockerCompose() {
  docker compose --env-file /tmp/pipeline.env \
    --file "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE" \
    --file /root/docker-compose.admin.yml \
    --profile "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROFILE" "$@"
  return $?
}

Some Logs
These are from my most recent build. I've removed my company's name, as well as most identifiers that would leak internal information.
Running with gitlab-runner 16.9.1 (782c6ecb)
  on gitlab-sh-runner-acme-yRsc4etL, system ID: ******
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:49
Using Docker executor with image docker.artifactory.acme.internal/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image:0.0.32 ...
Starting service docker.artifactory.acme.internal/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image:0.0.32 ...
Pulling docker image docker.artifactory.acme.internal/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image:0.0.32 ...
Using docker image sha256:93...ae3f for docker.artifactory.acme.internal/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image:0.0.32 with digest docker.artifactory.acme.internal/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image@sha256:fc...366c ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.857162682Z Custom Docker Daemon entrypoint script
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.931837814Z Searching for any Docker Compose file in the current working directory '/opt/app-root'
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943770881Z Unable to determine Docker Compose file to run.
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943789525Z Listing files that should have been created by dockerInitEnv
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943795773Z total 20
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943801309Z -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1994 Aug 29 19:45 pipeline.env
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943815776Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug 29 19:45 docker-compose-out
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943821870Z -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            35 Aug 29 19:45 artifactoryuser.env
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943827608Z -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           792 Aug 29 19:45 artifactorytoken.env
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:04.943833190Z Begin standard Docker Daemon entrypoint
...
Running on runner-yrsc4etl-project-219-concurrent-0 via runner-yrsc4etl-runner-acme-1724929080-25808ec7...
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:23.642960237Z time="2024-08-29T19:45:23.642637559Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
[service:my-dind-image] 2024-08-29T19:45:23.642983211Z time="2024-08-29T19:45:23.642662281Z" level=info msg="API listen on 0.0.0.0:2375"
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/acme/pipelines/cucumberjs-pipeline/.git/
Checking out 4cce2bab as detached HEAD (ref is refs/merge-requests/39/merge)...
Removing extension-version.dotenv
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:56
Using docker image sha256:93...ae3f for docker.artifactory.acme.internal/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image:0.0.32 with digest docker.artifactory.acme.internal/pipeline-images/pipelines-docker-integration-image@sha256:fc...366c ...
Custom Docker Daemon entrypoint script
Searching for any Docker Compose file in the current working directory '/opt/app-root'
Unable to determine Docker Compose file to run.
Listing files that should have been created by dockerInitEnv
total 20
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1994 Aug 29 19:45 pipeline.env
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug 29 19:45 docker-compose-out
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            35 Aug 29 19:45 artifactoryuser.env
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           792 Aug 29 19:45 artifactorytoken.env
Begin standard Docker Daemon entrypoint
$ cd $APX_UNIT_PATH
$ source $ENV
$ integration-test
Client:
 Version:    27.2.0
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.16.2
    Path:     /usr/local/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.29.2
    Path:     /usr/local/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 ...
Login Succeeded
Compose file indicated was found at '/builds/acme/pipelines/cucumberjs-pipeline/tests/docker/infra/local/docker-compose.yml'
 selenium-firefox Pulling 
 automated-tests Pulling 
 selenium-grid Pulling 
 ... 
 selenium-firefox Pulled 
 Network local_default  Creating
 Network local_default  Created
 Container apx-cucumberjs-unit-test-sg-hub  Creating
 Container apx-cucumberjs-unit-test-sg-hub  Created
 Container local-selenium-firefox-1  Creating
 Container local-selenium-firefox-4  Creating
 Container local-selenium-firefox-2  Creating
 Container local-selenium-firefox-3  Creating
 Container local-selenium-firefox-2  Created
 Container local-selenium-firefox-4  Created
 Container local-selenium-firefox-1  Created
 Container local-selenium-firefox-3  Created
 Container apx-cucumberjs-unit-test  Creating
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /tmp/artifactorytoken.env
Test Setup procedures failed with exit code 0 1
Running after_script
00:01
Custom Docker Daemon entrypoint script
Searching for any Docker Compose file in the current working directory '/opt/app-root'
Unable to determine Docker Compose file to run.
Listing files that should have been created by dockerInitEnv
total 24
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5982 Aug 29 19:46 pipeline.env
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug 29 19:46 docker-compose-out
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           105 Aug 29 19:46 artifactoryuser.env
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2376 Aug 29 19:46 artifactorytoken.env
Begin standard Docker Daemon entrypoint
Running after script...
$ if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == 'failed' ]; then # collapsed multi-line command
...
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1


Just to explain, I've been told that the GitLab runner cannot run a Docker Compose file directly. So we've been instructed to use a managed service of the docker:dind image to do so. In this last set of logs, I was testing a theory that the "path does not exist" error was because the managed service didn't have the file. This was why the custom-dockerd-entrypoint.sh script was added, so that I could make sure the files were present on both sides of the divide.
